# Keyword is not valid as an identifier : VB2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Hello we are trying to sort one of our strings out for an error message :

```
       Public ERROR As String
```

but we keep hitting the message Keyword is not valid as an identifier - Is there anyway around this error as the name cannot be changed from ERROR for the string

Thanks

Comment: http://techphile.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-vb-keywords-as-variables.html

Comment: Vb keyword-escape is `[Square brackets]` no? (in c# it is `@at`)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to name the variable something that is a known keyword? Is there any specific reason not to call it for instance ErrorMessage in stead?

Comment: It is just a combined output really of the coding that has already gone on in the previous set , it seemed more logical to try and find a way around it rather than go back and change it - it was one of those things that wasn't thought about until it was too late

Comment: In case it helps others, I got this with LinqPad.  The reason was my import statements in F4 (`Query Properties`) `Additional Namespace Imports` had included the keyword `IMPORT`, rather than simply listing the namespaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

> Public [ERROR] As String

The C# version would be:

> public string @ERROR;